# cannot start service from service

Tags: java, android

I'd like to achieve the following:
I have an old phone (android os) which I don't use anymore and like to put behind my window in our weekend house. I'd control it with firebase. When I add a child to a certain key, a service should trigger the phone's camera and take a photo. 
Now I have two things:

1. A simple service that listens to the firebase if anything changed
2. The camera service that takes pictures without any user interaction

My problem is that I can't combine these two things, as I can start startCapturing() method in APictureCapturingService from activities but not from services. How should I solve this? Thanks

```
public class FiBaService extends Service  {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_CODE = 1;
    //public APictureCapturingService pictureService;
    DatabaseReference mdb;
    String user, post;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleFIBA();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service is Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void handleFIBA() {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "dosomethingban!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child
            ("phones4streams").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            /*
            String userName = (dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)).toString();
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Userlist.add(String.valueOf(dsp.geValue())); //add result into array list
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, dsp.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(FiBa.this, userName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            */
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //String userName = (dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString());
            //Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Történt változás", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            //        .show();
            Toast.makeText(FiBaService.this, "Starting capture!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            //pictureService.startCapturing(FiBaService.this);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child
                    ("phones4streams").child("alamade").setValue("csalamade");
            takePic();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

APictureCapturingService - this handles the picture-taking:

```
public abstract class APictureCapturingService {

private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

private final Activity activity;

final Context context;
final CameraManager manager;

/***
 * constructor.
 *
 * @param activity the activity used to get display manager and the application context
 */
APictureCapturingService(final Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    this.manager = (CameraManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
}

/***
 * @return  orientation
 */
int getOrientation() {
    final int rotation = this.activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    return ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation);
}


/**
 * starts pictures capturing process.
 *
 * @param listener picture capturing listener
 */
public abstract void startCapturing(final PictureCapturingListener listener);
```

In other activites I instantiate this class like:

```
public APictureCapturingService pictureService;
pictureService = PictureCapturingServiceImpl.getInstance(this);
pictureService.startCapturing(SettingsActivity.this);
```

*EDITED*
trying with Broadcast Receiver I get the same: activity is required
[image]

PictureCapturingServiceImpl:

```
/**
 * The aim of this service is to secretly take pictures (without preview or opening device's
 * camera app)
 * from all available cameras using Android Camera 2 API
 *
 * @author hzitoun (zitoun.hamed@gmail.com)
 */

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) //NOTE: camera 2 api was added in API level 21
public class PictureCapturingServiceImpl extends APictureCapturingService {

    private static final String TAG = PictureCapturingServiceImpl.class.getSimpleName();

    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    /***
     * camera ids queue.
     */
    private Queue<String> cameraIds;

    private String currentCameraId;
    private boolean cameraClosed;
    /**
     * stores a sorted map of (pictureUrlOnDisk, PictureData).
     */
    private TreeMap<String, byte[]> picturesTaken;
    private PictureCapturingListener capturingListener;

    /***
     * private constructor, meant to force the use of {@link #getInstance}  method
     */
    private PictureCapturingServiceImpl(final Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
    }

    /**
     * @param activity the activity used to get the app's context and the display manager
     * @return a new instance
     */
    public static APictureCapturingService getInstance(final Activity activity) {
        return new PictureCapturingServiceImpl(activity);
    }

    /**
     * Starts pictures capturing treatment.
     *
     * @param listener picture capturing listener
     */
    @Override
    public void startCapturing(final PictureCapturingListener listener) {
        this.picturesTaken = new TreeMap<>();
        this.capturingListener = listener;
        this.cameraIds = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            final String[] cameraIds = manager.getCameraIdList();
            System.out.println("cameraIds length: " + cameraIds.length);
            System.out.println("cameraId[0]: " + cameraIds[0]);
            System.out.println("cameraId[1]: " + cameraIds[1]);
            if (cameraIds.length > 0) {
                this.cameraIds.addAll(Arrays.asList(cameraIds));
                // a currentCameraId lesz a cameraIds első eleme, de a caneraIds-ból remove-olva
                // lesz
                // ez az első elem
                this.currentCameraId = this.cameraIds.poll();
                openCamera();
            } else {
                //No camera detected!
                capturingListener.onDoneCapturingAllPhotos(picturesTaken);
            }
        } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred while accessing the list of cameras", e);
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        Log.d(TAG, "opening camera " + currentCameraId);
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                manager.openCamera(currentCameraId, stateCallback, null);
            }
        } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, " exception occurred while opening camera " + currentCameraId, e);
        }
    }


    private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession
            .CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull
                CaptureRequest request,
                                       @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
            if (picturesTaken.lastEntry() != null) {
                capturingListener.onCaptureDone(picturesTaken.lastEntry().getKey(), picturesTaken
                        .lastEntry().getValue());
                Log.i(TAG, "done taking picture from camera " + cameraDevice.getId());
            }
            closeCamera();
        }
    };


    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener onImageAvailableListener = (ImageReader
                                                                                           imReader) -> {
        final Image image = imReader.acquireLatestImage();
        final ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        saveImageToDisk(bytes, timeStamp);
        image.close();
    };


    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraClosed = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "camera " + camera.getId() + " opened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            Log.i(TAG, "Taking picture from camera " + camera.getId());
            //Take the picture after some delay. It may resolve getting a black dark photos.
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                try {
                    takePicture();
                } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, " exception occurred while taking picture from " +
                            currentCameraId, e);
                }
            }, 500);
        }


        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            Log.d(TAG, " camera " + camera.getId() + " disconnected");
            if (cameraDevice != null && !cameraClosed) {
                cameraClosed = true;
                cameraDevice.close();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onClosed(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraClosed = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "camera " + camera.getId() + " closed");
            //once the current camera has been closed, start taking another picture
            //if (!cameraIds.isEmpty()) {
            if (cameraIds.size() != 1 && !cameraIds.isEmpty()) {
                takeAnotherPicture();
            } else {
                capturingListener.onDoneCapturingAllPhotos(picturesTaken);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "camera in error, int code " + error);
            if (cameraDevice != null && !cameraClosed) {
                cameraDevice.close();
            }
        }
    };


    private void takePicture() throws CameraAccessException {
        if (null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics
                (cameraDevice.getId());
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics
                .SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        if (streamConfigurationMap != null) {
            jpegSizes = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        }
        final boolean jpegSizesNotEmpty = jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length;
        int width = jpegSizesNotEmpty ? jpegSizes[0].getWidth() : 640;
        int height = jpegSizesNotEmpty ? jpegSizes[0].getHeight() : 480;
        final ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        final List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest
                (CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation());
        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, null);
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        try {
                            session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, null);
                        } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, " exception occurred while accessing " + currentCameraId, e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    }
                }
                , null);
    }

    //cYou - átírva a képek mentési helye a cyou mappába 240. sor
    private void saveImageToDisk(final byte[] bytes, String timeStamp) {
        final String cameraId = this.cameraDevice == null ? UUID.randomUUID().toString() : this
                .cameraDevice.getId();
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mup/" +
                Sta.getCurrentTimeStamp() + "_pic.jpg");
        try (final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            output.write(bytes);
            this.picturesTaken.put(file.getPath(), bytes);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception occurred while saving picture to external storage ", e);
        }
    }

    private void takeAnotherPicture() {
        this.currentCameraId = this.cameraIds.poll();
        openCamera();
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        Log.d(TAG, "closing camera " + cameraDevice.getId());
        if (null != cameraDevice && !cameraClosed) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not launch an Activity from `FiBaService` and launch the `APictureCapturingService` from there?  It may seem a bit silly to have an Activity on the screen, because in your use case there won't be a user there to see it, but I suspect it will be easier than trying to capture images without an Activity (I think the camera API is probably not designed for that, since it would allow for malicious use of the camera).  You can use window flags in your Activity to ensure that it will show even if the screen is locked/off when the Activity launches, similar to how an alarm clock would work

Comment: Please post code directly instead of a screenshot. Also show `PictureCapturingServiceImpl` and its `getInstance()` function. What is the purpose of the `Activity` which your service accepts as a parameter in its constructor? And why do you call `getApplicationContext()` on it? A `Service` already extends `Context`, so none of this is necessary.

Comment: Note that an Activity is usually visually on the screen but a Service is usually not visual. You should use one or the other, but not both in the same class.

Comment: PictureCapturingServiceImpl added

Answer (score 1):

One solution is for the Firebase service to broadcast a message. Then implement a BroadcastReceiver to listen to the message and start your picture service when it is received.

I don't see any reason why you need an `Activity` in your code. It appears that you are trying to get a `Context` from the `Activity`. But `Service` already acts as a `Context`, so you can use it directly and simplify your constructor a lot:

```
APictureCapturingService() {
    this.manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
}
```

Now I assume you can get rid of the `Activity` parameter for `PictureCapturingServiceImpl.getInstance()` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I haven't used broadcast receivers yet, but where should I put that broadcast receiver? Because now the picture taking can only be started from an activity and I want to make that in the background.

Comment: @DenisDore I suggest you start by doing some research with Google. And official android dev site has tutorials on how to implement a broadcast receiver. (Hint: it's its own class.)

Comment: I did the research, and you were right broadcast receivers are really not rocket science, but I got the same results. Can you have a look at my edited part of the post? Thanks